# How to let angular frontend wait for express REST-Call response

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, express, axios

i want to make a REST-Call when i init my user Component so it will show the userprofile on load. This works fine, the component calls the service which calls my express backend which in turn makes a call to the REST-API which returns the userprofile. Then the Frontend gets updated.

However, i get a javascript error because the frontend tries to use the user.id before in the user components html template before the data is sent:

```
UserComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (UserComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:20458)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19833)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:20011)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19834)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:20011)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19834)
    at callViewAction (core.js:20069)
```

i tried to get around this behaviour by adding default values that i want to be used while the user gets loaded
Here is my HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li>id: {{user.id ? user.id : ''}}</li>
  <li>name: {{user.firstName ? user.firstName : ''}} {{user.lastName ? user.lastName : ''}}</li>
  <li>mail: {{user.email ? user.email : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
      console.log('myUser: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../classes/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<any>('/api/userprofile');
  }
}
```

and the serverside code

```
router.get('/userprofile', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('https://somerestapi', {auth: {username: 'authuser', password: 'authuserpw'}})
    .then(response => {
      res.status(200).json(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either put *ngIf="user" on the `ul` element. Or put the question mark after every `user` in the html. `<li>id: {{user?.id}}</li>`

Comment: Just checking the user object in the ngIf was enough. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ul *ngIf="user">
  <li>id: {{user.id ? user.id : ''}}</li>
  <li>name: {{user.firstName ? user.firstName : ''}} {{user.lastName ? user.lastName : ''}}</li>
  <li>mail: {{user.email ? user.email : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

You can  call a function inside the ngOnInit , like follows

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
      console.log('myUser: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
      this.assignUser(this.user) ;
    });
  }
  //function to assinging user value
      assignUser(user){
      this.user= user;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below html snippet:

```
<ul>
  <li>id: {{user?.id}}</li>
  <li>name: {{user?.firstName}} {{user?.lastName}}</li>
  <li>mail: {{user?.email}}</li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
  <ul *ngIf="user.length >0">
  <li>id: {{user.id ? user.id : ''}}</li>
  <li>name: {{user.firstName ? user.firstName : ''}} {{user.lastName ? user.lastName : ''}}</li>
  <li>mail: {{user.email ? user.email : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by checking the length of `user` array

```
<ul *ngIf="user.length >0">
  <li>id: {{user.id ? user.id : ''}}</li>
  <li>name: {{user.firstName ? user.firstName : ''}} {{user.lastName ? user.lastName : ''}}</li>
  <li>mail: {{user.email ? user.email : ''}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, this works as well. is there any reason why i should check for the length instead of just checking for the user object itself?